# How to get WooCommerce booking products in custom loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-bookings

i'm developing a Woocommerce Booking site for an Hotel, i'm stuck to find the way to have the url 'add to cart" for Woocommerce Booking in a custom loop. could someone please give me a little help whether is with `WP_Query` or `wc_get_products`. Any help would be appreciate. thx

Answer (score 1):

To get bookable products from WooCommerce Bookings plugin:

1). Using a `WC_Product_Query` *(see documentation [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query))*:

```
$products = wc_get_products( array(
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'type'      => 'booking',
    'limit'     => -1,
) );

// Loop through an array of the WC_Product objects
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    // Output linked product name (with add to cart url)
    echo '<p><a href="' . $product->add_to_cart_url() . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a></p>'; // The product name
}
```

2). Using a WP_Query *(see documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/))*:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
   'posts_per_page' =>  -1, 
   'post_type'      =>  array( 'product' ),
   'post_status'    =>  'publish',
   'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
        'terms'    => array( 'booking' ),
        'field'    => 'slug',
   )),
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
 
// Loop through an array of WP_Post objects
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

// Get the WC_Product Object (optional)
$product = wc_get_product();

// Output linked product name (with add to cart URL)
echo '<p><a href="' . $product->add_to_cart_url() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>'; // The product name

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

else :
// No post found
echo '<p>' . __("No products found", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
endif;
```

Both ways works…

> **Note for add to cart Url on bookable products:** 
> On Bookable products, you mostly can't get the add to cart URL as it involves some choices only possible in single product pages… So when using `WC_Product` `add_to_cart_url()` method your get the link to the single product page.

Comment: Thx for answering my question @LoicTheAztec, your answers are interesting but i need the "add to cart url button" like so:    `  <?php

       $products = wc_get_products( array(
        'status'    => 'publish',
        'type'      => 'booking',
        'limit'     => -1,
        'category' => 'el-dorado-royale'
     ));

     foreach ( $products as $product ) { ?>

      <a href="<?php   echo esc_url( $product->  add_to_cart_url() ); ?>"><?php   echo $product->add_to_cart_text(); ?></a>
<?php }


     ?>`

Comment: @Emmann You can't have an add to cart URL on most of bookable products (as they involves some choices only possible in single product pages)…

Comment: copy that @LoicTheAztec